# the specified field Could refer to more than one table listed in FROM clause

Tags: sql, ms-access, join

i have the following code.  my problem is i want to retrieve each employee name from another table name Employee which has a EmployeeID column similar to the AccessLog table, I used in this current query.  now when i m joining these 2 table it is giving that weird error i said on the title. without the added code for joining- A.EmployeeID, Employee.FirstName in the first SELECT and ;  AS A INNER JOIN Employee ON A.EmployeeID= Employee.EmployeeID to the last ORDER By clause, it is working good. I think problem is in the naming/alias. there are similar thread i saw, but those did not solve my problem. If someone could point me the fault, will appreciate.

```
SELECT **A.EmployeeID,
    Employee.FirstName,**
    MonthName(Month([LogDate])) AS MonthName,
    Round((Sum(Int(DateDiff("s",'00:00:00',Duration)))/3600)) AS TotalTime
    FROM (
         SELECT AccessLog.EmployeeID, 
                AccessLog.LogDate, 
                AccessLog.TerminalID, 
                AccessLog.LogTime, 
                Format((SELECT max(LogTime) 
                        FROM AccessLog AS Alias 
                        WHERE Alias.LogTime < AccessLog.LogTime 
                        AND Alias.EmployeeID = AccessLog.EmployeeID 
                        AND Alias.LogDate = AccessLog.LogDate 
                        AND (Alias.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1A" 
                        And (Alias.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1B"  
                        AND Alias.EmployeeID = AccessLog.EmployeeID),"hh:nn:ss") AS PrevTime, 
                Format((ElapsedTime(iif(PrevTime = '',logtime,prevtime),[LogTime])),"hh:nn:ss") AS Duration, 
                AccessLog.InOut 
             FROM AccessLog 
             WHERE (((AccessLog.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1A" 
             And (AccessLog.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1B") 
             AND ((AccessLog.EmployeeID) Like "2*") 
             AND ((AccessLog.InOut)="OUT")) 
             ORDER BY AccessLog.EmployeeID, AccessLog.LogDate, AccessLog.LogTime)  
             **AS A INNER JOIN Employee ON A.EmployeeID= Employee.EmployeeID**
      GROUP BY EmployeeID, MonthName(Month([LogDate]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it. As i said there is name/alias issue. I had to give seperate alias to the same table used in every subquery. even after that it show another error of aggragate function for the firstname in the top select, i also solved that by including it in a subquery. so in full my code goes as follows:

```
SELECT C.EmployeeID, 
   (SELECT Employee.FirstName& ' ' &Employee.LastName 
      FROM Employee 
      where C.EmployeeID= Employee.EmployeeID) 
    AS FullName, 
   MonthName(Month([LogDate])) AS MonthName,
   Round((Sum(Int(DateDiff("s",'00:00:00',Duration)))/3600)) AS TotalTime
   FROM (SELECT B.EmployeeID, 
              B.LogDate, 
              B.TerminalID, 
              B.LogTime, 
              Format((SELECT max(LogTime) 
                      FROM AccessLog AS A 
                      WHERE A.LogTime < B.LogTime 
                      AND A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID  
                      AND A.LogDate = B.LogDate 
                      AND (A.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1A" 
                      And (A.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1B"  
                      AND A.EmployeeID = B.EmployeeID),"hh:nn:ss") AS PrevTime,  
              Format((ElapsedTime(iif(PrevTime = '',logtime,prevtime),[LogTime])),"hh:nn:ss") AS Duration, 
              B.InOut 
              FROM AccessLog As B  
              WHERE (((B.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1A" 
               And (B.TerminalID)<>"iGuard1B") 
               AND ((B.EmployeeID) Like "2*") 
               AND ((B.InOut)="OUT")) 
               ORDER BY B.EmployeeID, B.LogDate, B.LogTime)  
AS C INNER JOIN Employee ON C.EmployeeID= Employee.EmployeeID
GROUP BY C.EmployeeID, MonthName(Month([LogDate]));
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it could be the `GROUP BY EmployeeId` - try changing that to either `GROUP BY A.EmployeeId` or `GROUP BY Employee.EmployeeId`.

Edit: It would probably have to be `GROUP BY A.EmployeeId`, as that's the one used the SELECT.

Comment: That gives me a new error-"you tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'firstname'as an aggregate function"

Comment: Ahh, because you're summing the duration, everything else in that SELECT statement needs to either be in an aggregate function, or in the GROUP BY clause. Adding Employee.FirstName to the GROUP BY clause would be the quick/easy way to solve it, but it could have unintended side-effects. If so, you'll probably need to refactor the query.

Comment: yeah that gives me data type mismatch error. don't know how to solve it, as new to This area.

Comment: Can you post the schema for AccessLog and Employee?

Comment: i tried uploading editing the post and include the schema jpg. but seems i cant upload image as i dont have that much reputaion. any idea how can i show you that image.

Comment: if you give me your email address, i can send to you the schema or the database itself.

Comment: i solved it. As i said there is name/alias issue. I had to give seperate alias to the same table used in every subquery. even after that it show another error of aggragate function for the firstname in the top select, i also solved that by including it in a subquery.